# Is it possible to push custom animation with 2 layer?

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

```
view 1 is current view
view 2 is view to push
```

is it possible to

```
 view 1 draw at top layer
 view 2 draw at bottom layer
```

move view 1 down to offscreen and at the same time CGAffineTransformMakeScale view 2 from 0.1 to 1.0

how can i do this ?

**Update**

i want to move all of screen(include navigationController) go down to the bottom of screen.
then my problem is when i draw both of this layer at navigationController
after i move navigationController down both of this layer will stick with navigationController

how can i make a temporary view to viewTopush(View 2) behind the navigationController and do animate

here is my code but it not yet work.

```
        RO_GALViewController *galView = [[RO_GALViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RO_GALViewController" bundle:nil];


        UINavigationController* navigationController;
        CGRect frame;


        navigationController = [self navigationController];

        frame = [navigationController.view convertRect:self.view.frame fromView:self.view.superview];

        galView.view.frame = frame;
        galView.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1);
        galView.view.alpha = 0;
        UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        blackView.alpha = 0;
        [[self navigationController].view addSubview:blackView];
        [[self navigationController].view addSubview:galView.view];
        [navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:self.view];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             galView.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                             galView.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
                             navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 460, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [[self navigationController] pushViewController:galView animated:NO];

                         }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put both animations inside your beginAnimations/commitAnimations code section.  It will do the animations simultaneously.  You don't have to worry about layers.

Answer (score 1):

The tags that you have added to this question (`uinavigationcontroller` and `pushviewcontroller`) suggest that you are talking about pushing a new view controller on screen but your description make it sound like both views are two subviews contained in the same view controller...

## If you are pushing a new view controller...

You can easily subclass UIStoryboardSegue to create your own animation. In your case you would change the position of the source view controllers view downwards and apply (and animate) the transform of the destination view controllers view. The animations themselves are just like any other animation.

## If both views are inside the same view controller...

Just do both animations. You could easily do them both at once using UIView animations, like this

```
view2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1); // the "from" value
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 // animate for 2 seconds
                 animations:^{
    view1.center = view1.center + theDistanceItShouldMoveDown;
    view2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; // no scale
}];
```